# How to configure Xbee S2C module(end device) in order to avoid merging of data at another Xbee S2C(coordinator)?

Tags: xbee

from India. I am working on a project where multiple xbee s2c devices form a star network, i.e., 1 coordinator and 3 end devices. Each end device attached to the Arduino Uno, coordinator to the NodeMCU.

I am collecting data from all 3 end devices and upload it into my website. But there is a small problem, sometimes the data from 2 or more end devices concatenates.

[image]

So 1 way to solve this issue might be write a code in NodeMCU to seperate data before posting it to website. 
But (I am an electronics student), I want to know if it is possible to avoid the merging of data at xbee coordinator device itself (maybe, by configuring it with a set of AT commands). 
I think a few times, the coordinator receives data from end devices consecutively which is making the serial buffer to perceive the incoming data as single large value. I provided sufficient delays between all 3 end devices, but still sometimes the data is merging.

I read in the datasheet(https://www.digi.com/resources/documentation/digidocs/pdfs/90002002.pdf) that CSMA-CA is implemented in the MAC layer, which means end device wont transmit data till it finds the channel free.

Should I allocate a seperate channel for each end device or should I try increasing baud rates? Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Byte stuffing might be the answer.

Comment: @Andy, yes, it sounds right. I will try it.

Comment: Please report back if u get some results.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you might be running in Transparent mode.  To avoid conflicts entirely you might need to use API mode.